# make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmpfr.so' in CGAL

Tags: c++, linux, cgal

I am using CGAL and I have this minimal example (which should be fine since it's an example):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <CGAL/Cartesian_d.h>
#include <CGAL/point_generators_d.h>
typedef CGAL::Cartesian_d<double> Kd;
typedef Kd::Point_d Point;
typedef CGAL::Creator_uniform_d<std::vector<double>::iterator, Point>Creator_d;
int main ()
{
  int nb_points = 10;
  int dim =5;
  double size = 100.0;
  std::cout << "Generating "<<nb_points<<" random points in a"
    <<" ball in "<<dim<<"D of center 0 and radius "<<size<<std::endl;
  std::vector<Point> v;
  v.reserve (nb_points);
  CGAL::Random_points_in_ball_d<Point> gen (dim, 100.0);
  for (int i = 0; i < nb_points; ++i) v.push_back (*gen++);
  for (int i = 0; i < nb_points; ++i) std::cout<<" "<<v[i]<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
samaras@samaras-A15:~/code/random_generator$ make
Scanning dependencies of target main
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmpfr.so', needed by `main'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What I should do?

I am creating the CmakeLists files like this:

```
~/code/CGAL-4.3/scripts/cgal_create_CMakeLists
cmake -DCGAL_DIR=$HOME/code/CGAL-4.3 .
```

as I describe [here](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/linux-and-cgal/).

If you need more information, please let me know.

--

```
cd /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmpfr.so
bash: cd: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmpfr.so: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I think you need to provide library switch like for pthread we need -pthread switch

Comment: Good point. So what should I do @YasirMajeed ?

Comment: Find a switch for your library :-)

Comment: If I knew where to search, I wouldn't ask @YasirMajeed ;p

Comment: is `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmpfr.so` a valid path? if not did you change your setting making this lib disappear?

Comment: See my edit @sloriot. I do not know, since I haven't use CGAL for ages!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to install CGAL on Debian or Ubuntu is `apt-get install libcgal-dev` (or `libcgal-qt4-dev`). If you are going to build CGAL yourself, you should still `apt-get build-dep cgal` which installs the most relevant dependencies.

Comment: Marc thanks for the answer, it deserves a +1. However, I am not accepting it, since it is more general, while the other answer ( mine :) ) is more concrete. Just for future readers: I built CGAL like I describe here: https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/linux-and-cgal/. And of course there is the installation manual from CGAL: http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/installation.html

Answer (score 1):

The library was missing after all, so I did this and we are OK:

```
sudo apt-get install libmpfr-dev libmpfr-doc libmpfr4 libmpfr4-dbg
```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/394296/how-to-install-mpfr-3-1-2-in-ubuntu-13-04)